# Troubleshoot a Friedman's non-parametric test using friedman.test.with.post.hoc function using R to analyze an RCBD experiment

Tags: r, statistics

I have a set of data obtained from an RCBD design. The data is the incidence of tipburn (i.e. a physiological leaf disorder caused by environmental factors, which is bad) in lettuce.

My experiment consisted of 3 blocks and 92 lettuce varieties from a Recombinant Inbred Line (i.e. RIL) population.

My goal is to analyze the data to find which varieties have a statistically significantly different tipburn incidence compared to other varieties.

My data does not meet the ANOVA assumptions of homogeneity of variances even after transformation; therefore, my next approach is to use a non-parametric test.  I found that I could analyze the data using a Friedman's test.  To conduct this test and to test which varieties have statistical differences from others I conveniently found a function at the following website:

http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/02/post-hoc-analysis-for-friedmans-test-r-code/

However, after formatting the data as indicated in the instructions I am having trouble running the function as seen below:

FORMATING THE DATA

```
    > tip.data.2011 = read.csv("Salinas_2011_tipburn_analysis.csv", header = TRUE)

    > head(tip.data.2011)
      RIL Block Tipburn_percentage
    1 110     1                0.0
    2 110     2                0.0
    3 110     3                0.0
    4 111     1               37.5
    5 111     2               12.5
    6 111     3               37.5

    > tip.data.2011.formated = data.frame( 
    +   Tipburn = tip.data.2011$Tipburn_percentage, 
    +     RIL = factor(rep(subset(tip.data.2011, Block == 1)[,1], rep(3, 92))),
    +   Block = factor(rep(1:3, 92))
    + )

    > head(tip.data.2011.formated)
      Tipburn RIL Block
    1     0.0 110     1
    2     0.0 110     2
    3     0.0 110     3
    4    37.5 111     1
    5    12.5 111     2
    6    37.5 111     3
```

RUNNING THE FUNCTION

```
    > friedman.test.with.post.hoc(Tipburn ~ RIL | Block, tip.data.2011.formated)
    Error in mvt(lower = lower, upper = upper, df = 0, corr = corr, delta = mean,  : 
      only dimensions 1 <= n <= 1000 allowed
```

I get the error message 'Error in mvt(lower = lower, upper = upper, df = 0, corr = corr, delta = mean,  : 
only dimensions 1 <= n <= 1000 allowed'

What does this error message mean?

Any ideas on how I can fix it?

Referring to @DWin's request:

```
    > with(tip.data.2011.formated, tapply(Tipburn, list(RIL, Block), length))
        1 2 3
    110 1 1 1
    111 1 1 1
    112 1 1 1
    113 1 1 1
    114 1 1 1
    115 1 1 1
    116 1 1 1
    117 1 1 1
    118 1 1 1
    119 1 1 1
    120 1 1 1 ... etc.
    198 1 1 1
    199 1 1 1
    200 1 1 1
    SAL 1 1 1

    > str(tip.data.2011.formated)
    'data.frame':   276 obs. of  3 variables:
     $ Tipburn: num  0 0 0 37.5 12.5 37.5 0 0 12.5 75 ...
     $ RIL    : Factor w/ 92 levels "110","111","112",..: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 ...
     $ Block  : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
```

I did the same procedure as shown above with a data set that does work (the data set is given in the website mentioned above).

```
    > WineTasting <- data.frame(
    +     Taste = c(5.40, 5.50, 5.55,
    +               5.85, 5.70, 5.75,
    +               5.20, 5.60, 5.50,
    +               5.55, 5.50, 5.40,
    +               5.90, 5.85, 5.70,
    +               5.45, 5.55, 5.60,
    +               5.40, 5.40, 5.35,
    +               5.45, 5.50, 5.35,
    +               5.25, 5.15, 5.00,
    +               5.85, 5.80, 5.70,
    +               5.25, 5.20, 5.10,
    +               5.65, 5.55, 5.45,
    +               5.60, 5.35, 5.45,
    +               5.05, 5.00, 4.95,
    +               5.50, 5.50, 5.40,
    +               5.45, 5.55, 5.50,
    +               5.55, 5.55, 5.35,
    +               5.45, 5.50, 5.55,
    +               5.50, 5.45, 5.25,
    +               5.65, 5.60, 5.40,
    +               5.70, 5.65, 5.55,
    +               6.30, 6.30, 6.25),
    +     Wine = factor(rep(c("Wine A", "Wine B", "Wine C"), 22)),
    +     Taster = factor(rep(1:22, rep(3, 22))))

    > with(WineTasting, tapply(Taste, list(Wine, Taster), length))
           1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
    Wine A 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
    Wine B 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
    Wine C 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1

    > str(WineTasting)
    'data.frame':   66 obs. of  3 variables:
     $ Taste : num  5.4 5.5 5.55 5.85 5.7 5.75 5.2 5.6 5.5 5.55 ...
     $ Wine  : Factor w/ 3 levels "Wine A","Wine B",..: 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
     $ Taster: Factor w/ 22 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 ...
```

My data appears to be formated in the same way as the example data set that does run. I don't think that having a large number of 1 observation for tipburn is the problem.

Thank you,

Miguel

Comment: OP has reposted at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62686/troubleshoot-a-friedmans-non-parametric-test-using-friedman-test-with-post-hoc

Comment: This has now been closed as off-topic on CrossValidated.com because it is "about programming" and closed as off-topic on SO because it is "not about programming". Is there some sort of stackexchange appeals court that Miguel can turn to for redress?)

Comment: Glad to see it's open again here; this does seem like the right place for it.

Answer (score 2):

(I was unimpressed with the comments in the CrossValidated exchange.) The question is why you are getting an error with Tal Galili's code. Downloading the code from that webpage shows that the error message must be coming from one of the packages on which it depends since that error is not thrown within that function. The function throwing the error is `mvt` and yet that function is not in any of the packages mentioned in the code, at least when I look at the most recent versions of those packages. (Turns out it is in `mvtnorm` which is attached by `multcomp`.) The code in `mvt` that is throwing the error is

```
if (n > 1000) 
    stop("only dimensions 1 <= n <= 1000 allowed")
```

So I suspect that your problem is larger than anticipated by the authors of `multcomp` and by extension `mvtnorm`. Can you look at:

```
  with(tip.data.2011.formated,  
               tapply(Tipburn, list(RIL,  Block), 
                                  length) ) )
```

Given your results for that diagnostic inquiry, I'm guessing that you have a malformed `RIL` or `Block` variable. You have a large number of categories with a single value for `Tipburn`. Try also posting ... this time as an edit to your question ... the results of `str(tip.data.2011.formated)`.

In the code that succeeded the factor with the small number of categories "Wine" was the "main effects" variable. In your setup the factor with 92 levels was given as the "main effects" variable and the variable with the small number of categories as the stratification variable. I don't think you ever expressed a specific hypothesis that was being tested, in particular what meaning is attached to "Block" values, so I am not sure what the question is. If it makes sense to reverse the order of those variables, i.e. if the question is whether Block differences are important, you should try the formula: `Tipburn ~ Block | RIL`

I'm also concerned that you may have reduced this dataset from raw data to a processed version, and that analysis with `glm` on the original count data might make more sense. Analyzing proportions suggest this started out as "count data".

Comment: What do you mean by 'a malformed `RIL` or `Block` variable'?

Comment: I'm coming around to thinking they are not so much malformed as 'mal-positioned'. If the question is whether there are difference in the effects of some environmental factors (presumably differences between Blocks) then Blocks should be the "main effects" variable.